Why is command listing delaying the control release of a subshell?
In Bash, running the following:
( sleep 50  > /dev/null 2>&1 &) &&  exit 0 

exits before my human eye can even notice.
But if I list commands within the group
( sleep 50 && sleep 50  > /dev/null 2>&1 &) &&  exit 0

it will pause for like 2 seconds displaying
exit

It does the same if I switch && for || or ; or any kind of listing or if I wrap the parenthesis grouping for { command1 ; command2 ; }
The only things that seem to get that blazing speed again are:

using
( bash -c 'sleep 50 && sleep 50'  > /dev/null 2>&1 &) &&  exit 0


putting all this in a script
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sleep 50 || sleep 50

( ./wrapperScript.sh  > /dev/null 2>&1 &) &&  exit 0 



And I can't understand why it does so.
My assumptions were that a subshell ( c1 || c2 && c3 ;; c4 ) would be equivalent (enough) to putting all this in a script but it's not (at all).
There seem to be a forking optimization when a group is not a compound but I don't know why it would display the exiting message for longer.
I could use a wrapping script (probably will for the time being) but this is itching my mind, i GOT to know why there's this (negligible yet annoying) delay.
(I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious.)

Which distribution of Linux are you using ? Are you running under WSL ? git-bash ?

linux mint native on any terminal (gnome-term / terminator)

What does bash --version say?

I can't reproduce this (maybe different environment?), but it may have to do with the fact that stdout and stderr are still connected to the terminal until the second sleep command starts. Try ( exec >/dev/null 2>&1 </dev/null; sleep 50 && sleep 50 &) &&  exit 0

@oguzismail 5.1.16

@GordonDavisson : no difference :(

I can't reproduce this in bash 5.1.4 on Debian.

Can you reproduce it if you disable your shell startup scripts (e.g. .profile and .bashrc)? Maybe something you're customizing is causing the problem.

I can reproduce it on Gnome terminal but not Xterm. I don't think this has much to do with bash

A single pipeline means that both commands are executed at once. Double pipeline means execute the second command if the first fails. Double ampersand means only execute the second command if the first is successful. And the semicolon executes both commands, one before the other no matter the exit status of the previous one, as if they were in 2 separate lines on a script. On the first line you posted ###( sleep 50  > /dev/null 2>&1 &) &&  exit 0 ###, you are setting the sleep command in background by setting the last ampersand before the closing parentheses (you execute things in background like "command &") so the script doesnt wait for it to finish. If you remove it, it will do the full sleep.

What you say is exact, but my question was rather "why is there a delay" and it seems, as other comments on my question pointed out, that those are due either on my bash or terminal implementation. So you are perfectly correct but what you said was not the point of my question. Thanks though to have taken the time to put up such a clear explanation of what you thought the problem was.
